# Error: Could not find or load main class HelloServlet IDEA TomCat

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, tomcat

что я делаю не так? сервер установил правильно и он работает на убунту, онзапущен, локалхост показывает страницу апатча, а мой проект не запускается

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp -Dmaven.home=/home/klimenkov/idea-IU-172.4343.14/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/klimenkov/idea-IU-172.4343.14/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -javaagent:/home/klimenkov/idea-IU-172.4343.14/lib/idea_rt.jar=42275:/home/klimenkov/idea-IU-172.4343.14/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/klimenkov/idea-IU-172.4343.14/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.2.5 tomcat7:run -P clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Malformed POM /home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'modelversion' (position: START_TAG seen .../4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">\n  <modelversion>... @3:17)  @ /home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/pom.xml, line 3, column 17
[FATAL] 'groupId' is missing. @ line 2, column 106
[FATAL] 'artifactId' is missing. @ line 2, column 106
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Malformed POM /home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'modelversion' (position: START_TAG seen .../4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">\n  <modelversion>... @3:17)  @ /home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/pom.xml, line 3, column 17 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'groupId' is missing. @ line 2, column 106
[ERROR]     'artifactId' is missing. @ line 2, column 106
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Почему не импортирует пакеты?

pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelversion>4.0.0</modelversion>
  <groupid>org.mycompany.myname</groupid>
  <artifactid>mywebapp</artifactid>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mywebapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>mywebapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>8888</port>
          <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сервлет должен реализовывать интерфейс `HttpServlet` из импортируемого вами пакета `javax.servlet.http`. Зачем вы вообще в противном случае импортируете их? Все, что должен делать сервлет, происходит в переопределяемых методах, вроде `doGet`.

Также вы должны провести маппинг сервлета в файле web.xml или при помощи аннотаций (это не отменяет обязательность существования web.xml).

Ваш код заработает, если написать его так:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "ServletName", urlPatterns = "/index.html")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()){
            out.write("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1509877942/8d0b6ac2/19287525.png

Он эти подчеркивает красным

Comment: В pom.xml замените modelversion, groupid, artifactid на modelVersion, groupId, artifactId

Comment: Это я сделал. Как определить эти версии? что тут писать? то , что красным.

https://pp.userapi.com/c824411/v824411921/1582c/yd6flGpOXOU.jpg

Comment: Исправил все ошибки,красным перестало подчеркивать после обновления плагинов и добавления их, еще версиюджавы поменял, но...
.../home/klimenkov/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar HelloServlet
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloServlet

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете, как в целом сервлеты работают? Вам не нужно **запускать** этот код, вам нужно скомпилировать его и передать Tomcat, который знает, что нужно делать с .class